# Queue, Jobs and Scheduler - Existing Patterns or Libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, queue, jobs

I am designing an application that needs to work with a queue of jobs, that can be handled by any worker server.  The jobs are stored in the database, and vary in type.  I have an idea for a design which is outlined below:

Each job implements an `IJob`, and the sub types contain all the properties needed to run the job.  Workers will pull the next job in the list from the database, and start processing it, logging progress back to the database periodically.

Jobs need to be added to this queue on a periodic basic, which could be every 5sec, 10sec, 30sec, 1min, 5min, 10min, 1hour ...... 1 year, 2year (you get the picture).  So I need some form of Cron job to trigger these events.  For example, 1 job may be download and process email attachements from a certain mailbox every hour.

My ideal solution would be a pattern that allows the workers to be replicated and work without conflict, while also not worrying about 1 "master worker" which populates these jobs.

My current design for this involves a separate database table to track which "periodic" jobs have been completed, and each worker does atomic updates on this table every second.  If a periodic job needs creating and hasn't been done, the worker will create it.  Each worker program will be triggered by a windows task, set to run once per second.

I believe this should all work ok, however I figured this much be such a common requirement, there must be known patterns or tools out there, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

So questions:

- Am I reinventing the wheel?!
- Is the pattern I'm using sensible, or can it be improved?
- Is there any third party libraries that do this for .NET?

Current Stack is .NET / C# running on Windows Servers (AWS EC2), with a MongoDB backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) seems to fit most of your criteria to a 'T'.  Including having something called, literally,  `IJob` ;).

Combined with using RabbitMQ or custom database tables simulating a queue, you now have jobs processing queued inputs at regular intervals.

That being said, if you want this to be distributed (i.e. have multiple servers running these jobs) you will need a SQL database in the vanilla Quartz.NET distro.  Seems like there are MongoDB adapters available, though I've never used one.

Comment: Quartz is perfect. Very quick and easy to use, got it running with the MongoDb JobStore no problem.  Saved me countless hours!  Thanks